# What is the grammar behind the phrase ‘all the better’

Tags: grammaticality, idioms

I have used the sentence ‘In general, the doctors weren’t all the much better.’ in an article I’m writing; to me it sounds perfectly well, but to my advisor, it didn’t. Is it grammatically and idiomatically correct, and if so, how can I explain the grammar behind it?

Comment: You're close. It should be *the doctors weren't all that much better*.

Comment: *all the much better* is definitely not idiomatic. Anything that wants to modify an "article + comparative" will have to come before the article. E.g. *so much the better*, *any the less*. If the thing you are writing is scholarly (i.e. formal), *were not much better* should do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following idiomatic expression is used to convey a different meaning from what you are probably suggesting. You should probably  say...."*In general the doctors were not (so) much better*"

***[All the better](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/all%20the%20better)***/***[so much the better](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/so-much-the-better)***:

> - used to say that something makes a situation, experience, etc., even better than it was:
>
>   - *My daughter loves taking care of children. If she can earn money by doing it, so much the better!*

(M-W) (Cambridge Dictionary)

Note: in your sentence "better" is an adjective, while in the idiomatic expressions "the better" is a noun.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. It would seem I wrongly assumed you could add modifiers between the article and noun, but that obviously made the expression sound strange. As I understand you, the expressions are either ‘all the better’ or ‘so much the better’; one cannot use ‘much’ with ‘all the better’.